# UIButton not showing Image

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am about to introduce Checkboxes in my app, and I came across [XLabs' solution](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/CheckBox) for it, after I had made my own Checkbox implementation on UWP.

Now I have a problem with the iOS. 
My code for CheckBoxView looks just like the one mentioned above

```
namespace MyProject.iOS.ViewRenderers
{
   [Register("CheckBoxView")]
   public class CheckBoxView : UIButton
   {
      public bool Checked
      {
         get { return Selected; }
         internal set { Selected = value; }
      }

      public CheckBoxView()
      {
         Initialize();
      }

      public CheckBoxView(CGRect frame)
         : base(frame)
      {
         Initialize();
      }

      private void Initialize()
      {
         AdjustEdgeInsets();
         ApplyStyle();

         TouchUpInside += (sender, args) => Selected = !Selected;
         SetTitle("Test", UIControlState.Normal);
         SetTitleColor(UIColor.DarkTextColor, UIControlState.Normal);
         SetTitleColor(UIColor.DarkTextColor, UIControlState.Selected);
      }

      private void AdjustEdgeInsets()
      {
         const float Inset = 8f;

         HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left;
         ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0f, Inset, 0f, 0f);
         TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0f, Inset * 2, 0f, 0f);
      }

      private void ApplyStyle()
      {
         SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/Checkbox/Unchecked.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
         SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/Checkbox/Checked.png"), UIControlState.Selected);
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is, that the pictures are not shown up netiher on Simulator or real device.

My pictures are saved in the right folder, which you can see at this image [image: Pictures' location]

The pictures' **Build action** is set to `BundleResource`, and **Copy to Output Directory** to `Copy Always`.

What can I have done wrong?
The text is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
`SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Unchecked.png"), UIControlState.Normal);` ?

Comment: Yes, but without success

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FromBundle`, Use function `FromFile`.

```
 SetImage(UIImage.FromFile("Images/Checkbox/Unchecked.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: The same thing occurs (returning null as UIImage)